# Jordan region problem

Tags: real-analysis

What is a Jordan Region? I can't find the definition anywhere. The question asked, if $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, bounded and with finitely many accumulation points, then $E$ is Jordan region.

Comment: I think this refers to [Jordan measurable sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure).

Answer (score 7):

From pg. 384 of An Introduction to Analysis (3rd Edition) by William R. Wade:

12.3 Definition. Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $E$ is said to be a *Jordan region* if and only if given $\epsilon > 0$ there is rectangle $R \supseteqq E$, and a grid $\mathcal{G} = \lbrace R_{1}, \ldots, R_{p} \rbrace$ on $R$, such that

$$
V(\partial E; \mathcal{G}) := \sum_{R_{j} \bigcap \partial E \neq \emptyset} |R_{j}| < \epsilon.
$$

... Thus a set is a Jordan region if and only if its boundary is so thin that it can be covered by rectangles whose total volume is as small as one wishes.

Comment: Can you give an example in R^2 or R^3?