# Any function of class $\mathcal C^{1}$ maps Jordan measurable set onto Jordan measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know the following fundamental property of functions of class $\mathcal C^{1}$:

> Let $S$ be open in $\mathbb R^{n}$;let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n}$ be a function 
>   of  class $\mathcal C^{1}$.If the subset $A$ of $S$ has *Lebesgue measure zero* in  $\mathbb R^{n}$,then the set 
>   $f(A)$ also has *Lebesgue measure zero* in $\mathbb R^{n}.(\star)$

If we replace *Lebesgue measure zero* by [*Jordan region*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251627/jordan-region-problem) (i.e. *Jordan measurable set*) in $(\star)$, the last argument  may not be correct. I want to find some  counterexamples to confirm the last argument is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a counterexample: Let $S:=\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\>|\>-1<x<1\}$ and consider
$$f: \quad(x,y)\mapsto\bigl({\rm artanh\,}x,0\bigr)\ .$$
The set $A:=\ ]{-1},1[\>\times\{0\}\subset S$ has Jordan measure $0$, but $f(A)={\mathbb R}\times\{0\}$ is not Jordan measurable.

But if you assume in addition that the set $A$ is compact then you will be able to prove that $f(A)$ has Jordan measure $0$. This follows from global Lipschitz estimates for $f$ valid on $A$.